# Need variable to name another variable for column conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, variables

[image]

I am looping through all headers to create named ranges. I need to also use the i variable in loop to create variable names to use columns for conditional formatting.

This is what I can come up with, but obviously not working for me.

```
Sub Naming_For_Cond_Formatting()

     ShtLastColNum = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

     For i = 1 To ShtLastColNum - 1

          HeaderNme = Cells(1, i).Value

          ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)

          Names.Add Name:=HeaderNme, RefersTo:=Columns(i)

          HeaderNme & "_Col" = ColumnLetter

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: "Variable variables" don't exist. Can you explain what your end goal is in general terms? What is the conditional formatting you're trying to create?

Comment: I need variable names for the columns to use for conditional formatting. The columns can be in different order so it's better for me to use the column header as variable for column when setting up conditional formatting through VBA

ie: Entity_Col to reference column A, Status_Col to reference column B
(based on example image, though could be a different column next time user opens file)

If there is a better logic to achieve this, I'm all for learning

Comment: If `HeaderNme & "_Col" = ColumnLetter` actually did work, exactly how would you use that variable `HeaderNme & "_Col` later in VBA?

Comment: This is just one example (I have many conditional formats with columns that aren't always in the same order)

        Range(Candidate_Col & "2:" & Status_Col & "100").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=SEARCH(""final"",$" & Candidate_Col & "1)"
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .Color = 11184810
            End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Comment: Basically, I need to use a variable (preferably the value of 1st cell in column is header) to make it easier to name column letters in formulas later in the sub

Comment: There is a difference between assigning a strings to a variable and changing the name of the variable.

Comment: Yes, my apologies, ShtLastColNum , HeaderNme and ColumnLetter are dim as string. Is the type of variable what I need to fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is good case for the Dictionary object. I have added some lines to your code to create and populate the dictionary. Finally, a way of how to access it:

```
Sub Naming_For_Cond_Formatting()
     Dim HeaderNames As Object
     Set HeaderNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     ShtLastColNum = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
     For i = 1 To ShtLastColNum - 1
          HeaderNme = Cells(1, i).Value
          ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, i).Address, "$")(1)
          Names.Add Name:=HeaderNme, RefersTo:=Columns(i)
          HeaderNames.Add HeaderNme & "_Col", ColumnLetter
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print HeaderNames("Notes_Col")
End Sub
```